# conver to html entites only not matching tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using: `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper.sanitize` in order to get rid of some html tags, however I'm interested in convert to html entities all the non-matching tags.

For example, giving this text:

```
<b>this is an acceptable tag<b> <iframe>this is not acceptable</iframe>
```

I'm interested in get this output

```
<b>this is an acceptable tag<b> &lt;iframe&gt;this is not acceptable&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify allowed tags as options to the `sanitize` method.

```
sanitize @comment.body, tags: %w(strong em a), attributes: %w(href)
```

Check for more information [ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)